# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n \frac{a_n}{n}$

Tags: analysis, power-series

For $n \in \mathbb{N}^\star$, define $a_n := \frac{1 \times 3 \times \cdots \times (2n-1)}{2 \times 4 \times \cdots \times (2n)}$ and $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}  \frac{a_n}{n} x^{2n}$.

One easily gets by induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^\star, a_n \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$ and this helps us show that $f$ is continuous on $[-1, 1]$.

Let $S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n x^{2n}$. One shows that :

$$
\forall x \in (-1, 1), S(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} - 1
$$

How do I use that to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n \frac{a_n}{n}$ ? I see it is $f(i)$, but I have no idea how to use this and $S$ to get a clean expression. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $f'(x)=\frac{2S(x)}{x}$, you can then integrate $S$ and use the fact that $f(0)=0$ to get the integration constant.

Comment: I made the edit, I missed a sqrt @user

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {a_n}nx^{2n}=f(x)=2\int_0^x\frac {S (t)}t dt=2\log\frac2 {1+\sqrt {1-x^2}}.\tag1
$$
Substituting into (1) $x=i$ one obtains:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac {a_n}n=f (i)=\log (12-8\sqrt2).\tag2
$$

Comment: The downvoter is welcome to communicate his/her suggestions for improving the answer.

Comment: The downvoter has disappeared ....now.

Comment: I would like an answer which is not using analytical functions theory (which I don't master and which it seems you're using).
To me, the first line you wrote is valid, but as far as I know/can understand, only for real values of $x$ in $(-1, 1)$.
The function $x \mapsto \sqrt{1 - x^2}$, even if defined at $x = i$, is not defined on the complex unit circle generally speaking.

The downvote only meant the current answer isn't satisfying in these regards.
But I thank you a lot for this answer @user